# Flutter: Radio Button in Modal Sheet like this

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create a radio button group like this inside my modal sheet in Flutter? Here is a picture showing this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzpgg.jpg

Thank you in advance.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

void _showModalSheet() {
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return new Container(
        height: 300,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Please Choose", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Divider(height: 20.0, color: Colors.grey,),
            Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Mutton Bone Curry"),
                  Spacer(),
                  new Radio(
                    onChanged: (int e) => something(e),
                    activeColor: Colors.blue,
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: groupValue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Vegetable Kuruma"),
                Spacer(),
                new Radio(
                  onChanged: (int e) => something(e),
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  value: 2,
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Chicken Curry"),
                Spacer(),
                new Radio(
                  onChanged: (int e) => something(e),
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  value: 3,
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

@override
int groupValue;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Flutter BottomSheet"),
  ),
  body: new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _showModalSheet,
              child: new Icon(Icons.control_point),
            ),
          ],
        )),
  ),
);
}

void something(int e) {
setState(() {
  if (e == 1) {
    groupValue = 1;
  } else if (e == 2) {
    groupValue = 2;
  } else if (e == 3) {
    groupValue = 3;
  }
});
}}
```

so far I have been able to achieve this. The only problem is that once a button is ticked, the change cannot be seen immediately . You can only see it after you go back to the centre of the screen (where control_point icon is).

Comment: What is exactly your problem / error ?

Comment: May be you have to look into that, try it best of luck, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12882

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel so far I have been able to achieve that code up there, the only problem is that when you click a button it does not change immediately you have to first go back to main screen and then come back to the Radio Buttons again to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and I managed to handle this case inside a StreamBuilder, since I don't want to call setState() {} that will refresh the complete page.

I copy / paste my solution, it is simple, and you will figure it out by yourself

```
final manager = Provider.of<FilterManager>(context, listen: false);
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => StreamBuilder(
        stream: manager.selectedItemChanges,
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<SortItem> snapshot) => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: manager.items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, pos) => RadioListTile(
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                title: Text(manager.items[pos].label),
                value: manager.items[pos],
                groupValue: snapshot.data,
                onChanged: (item) => manager.setFilter(item)))));
```

`manager.setFilter()` triggers a new item emitted inside the stream `selectedItemChanges`